# Can you embedd an html 5 canvas app/page into a users feed (news / wall)?

Tags: facebook, html, canvas

I have a requirement to allow users to add a stream story to their feeds.  Our app is simple - it has a play icon and when a user clicks it it plays a clip of a song they created.

I have this working on an HTML 5 page and would like to not have to build a flash swf for this if I can help it.  I would like it to post to the users' stream and allow them to click on the icon and play the clip in their stream (just embed the canvas page in an iframe) I have the authentication, user approval (one being publish_stream), access_token, and publish (using FB.ui JS) and it looks great. But when a user clicks the icon it just navigates off of Facebook to the website page (same as canvas page) from the link provided in the FB.ui.
My question(s) is: Is there a way to specify, either in app setup or during the post, to embed the canvas page (not swf) into an iframe or have it in a popup? If not will it automatically embed a swf file or so I have to do anything special with that?

Thanks so much for any help!!
I have read, searched and tested code for this info for days with no luck
Estaban

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't currently publish a canvas to stream. The only media types allowed are flash, image, and mp3 (as attachments).

Comment: One more question - I tried publishing a swf file with the same results (opening the page the swf was in) How do I tell Facebook its a swf so it needs to be in an iframe. Do I just point the link: attribute directly to the swf or to the html page hosting the swf?   Thanks very much!

Comment: Just like images and mp3s, attaching is the best you can do for using an swf in publish_stream. See the guide here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/. I'm not sure you can change how facebook chooses to open it (in the frame or on another page).

Comment: Hey Simon, According to FAcebook Facebook.streamPublish is going away and already not supported. I am trying to use FB.ui but no real documentation on this with an attachment. I tried using the word attachment as the key (also media) with the json array and no luck. Do you know of a sample js doing an attachment so I can model this properly?  Really thanks for your help! you are a lifesaver.